# How to add a blank line onto a scoreboard in Minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Recently I am working on a RPG custom map. I wonder if there are any ways to insert a blank line (in singleplayer) onto the scoreboard to make it more fancier and more organized, just like this scoreboard from Hypixel:

[[image]

As you can see, there are spaces in-between "Gold: 1710" and "www.hypixel.net".
That's exactly what I want to achieve.

Comment: I dont think it is possible with pure commands. I found [this](https://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/minecraft-java-edition/redstone-discussion-and/commands-command-blocks-and/2945096-is-it-possible-to-have-a-blank-line-in-a) for commands which show some workarounds and [this](https://www.spigotmc.org/threads/how-do-i-add-blank-variables-on-my-scoreboard.157938/) for plugins which kinda show that it is meant to be done with plugins.